# SQLite: Use SELECT instead of TEMP TABLE

Tags: sqlite

I have an SQLite query that creates a temporary table, followed by a SELECT statement. I'd like to figure out how to write the query without using the temporary table, so that I can use it as a view. Can someone point me to some examples where this is done?

Comment: How exactly are you creating the temporary table? Show your code.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't have to use `temptable` in your `view`  you can use the following statement to creat view from your `select` :

```
    CREATE VIEW v_tracks 
    AS 
    SELECT
    trackid,
    tracks.name,
    albums.Title AS album,
    media_types.Name AS media,
    genres.Name AS genres
    FROM
    tracks
```

From now on, you just use the following simple query:

```
    SELECT
    *
    FROM
    v_tracks;
```

[Try it Here](http://www.sqlitetutorial.net/tryit/query/sqlite-create-view/#2)

and if you have to use temp table in a view , you can use `CTEs`, CTEs are temporary result sets that are defined within the execution scope of a single statement and they can be used in views.

an Example from [here](http://www.sqlusa.com/bestpractices2005/viewwithcte/) :

```
    CREATE VIEW vSalesStaffQuickStats
    AS
    WITH SalesBySalesPerson (SalesPersonID, NumberOfOrders, MostRecentOrderDate)
    AS
    (
          SELECT SalesPersonID, COUNT(*), MAX(OrderDate)
          FROM Sales.SalesOrderHeader
          GROUP BY SalesPersonID
    )
    SELECT E.EmployeeID,
    EmployeeOrders = OS.NumberOfOrders,
    EmployeeLastOrderDate = OS.MostRecentOrderDate,
    E.ManagerID,
    ManagerOrders = OM.NumberOfOrders,
    ManagerLastOrderDate = OM.MostRecentOrderDate
    FROM   HumanResources.Employee AS E
           INNER JOIN SalesBySalesPerson AS OS
               ON E.EmployeeID = OS.SalesPersonID
           LEFT OUTER JOIN SalesBySalesPerson AS OM
               ON E.ManagerID = OM.SalesPersonID
```

i hope it helps.

Comment: As far as I know, views cannot make use of temporary tables.

Comment: instead making temp table it's better to make a view

Comment: Yes, I know that already. I am trying to make a view that does the same thing that I am currently using a temporary table to do. All of this is stated in my original question.

Comment: @dkj i added an example if you have to use temp table in a view.